# Remove xml:space="preserve" of XML file using C#

Tags: c#, xml

I used this code to export to XML file from DataTable:

```
dt1 = TNET2_POHeadService.TNET2_POHead_GetByPO_NoRaw(PO_No);
                dt2 = TNET2_PODetailsService.TNET2_PODetails_GetByPO_NoRaw(PO_No);
                ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
                ds.Tables[0].TableName = "TNET2_POHead";
                ds.Tables.Add(dt2);
                ds.Tables[1].TableName = "TNET2_PODetails";
                saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

                ds.WriteXml(saveFileDialog1.FileName);
```

Everything worked fine but :

```
<ContractNo>P1717-198905-003(01)</ContractNo>
<KP_No xml:space="preserve">             </KP_No>
<SettlementRoute1>TENTAC SUZHOU</SettlementRoute1>
```

KP_No tag is blank value. I want to remove xml:space="preserve" of the XML export file. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **XDocument** class in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace allows for easy manage and manipulation of XML using LINQ.

See example below to remove the `xml:space="preserve"` attribute from the *KP_No* element of the XML file:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml"); // or XDocument.Load(myStream) ...

Func<XAttribute, bool> preserveAttrFunc = atr => atr.Name.LocalName == "space" && atr.Value == "preserve";
XElement kp_no = doc.Descendants("KP_No").FirstOrDefault(kp => kp.HasAttributes && kp.Attributes().Any(preserveAttrFunc));

if(kp_no != null)
    kp_no.Attributes().FirstOrDefault(preserveAttrFunc).Remove();

// doc.Save(filename) ...
```

Note your XML doesn´t have a root element. It's good practice to have one defined in XML.

Result after the code snippet above:

```
<root>
  <ContractNo>P1717-198905-003(01)</ContractNo>
  <KP_No></KP_No>
  <SettlementRoute1>TENTAC SUZHOU</SettlementRoute1>
</root>
```